# What does actually Lost RAM mean in dumpsys meminfo

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

When i get memory information using `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` it shows something called **LOST RAM**. I know that this equals to `TOTAL - FREE RAM - USED RAM` but i need to know what this really means.

- Is it just a calculation error/issue ? or
- Do this amount(**LOST RAM**) is
  really lost because of some hardware or other bug?.

If this is really a bug and not a calculation error so then should i go for a device with low **LOST RAM** when i'm buying an android device. and should i avoid devices with high **LOST RAM** value. Please provide me a clear answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lost RAM is just RAM that is unaccounted for, it will take all the processes ram usage and add them up the difference between that value and the actual amount of ram left is known as lost ram because the OS can't account for what is using it. It's software related and from what I read can be from ION debug, or drivers that allocate and track their own ram. I don't think it should play any part in your consideration when buying a new android device though.

Comment: Yeah but if it can't be re-claimed(I assume since we only use FREE RAM to make new allocations so LOST RAM is unusable) even if it is a software level bug i will have a low amount of memory available if i have a device with high LOST RAM right?. And is there any reliable source/documentation about this LOST RAM because most of the stuff i have read on internet about this are bit uncertain and has no clear answer.

Comment: It can't be reclaimed because it's being used, it's not waisted. It's still being used by some process such as a driver. The OS just isn't aware of it so it marks it as lost.

Comment: I have no backing for this but I would assume that a phone with a lot of features like touch pens, etc.. Would possibly have more lost ram as a result of the extra drivers taken to run those things. I don't really think it should impact which phone you buy.

Comment: Thanks point taken. But i guess it will remain around that value(LOST RAM value) always so if i'm very concern about available free memory for my app then i should look for a device with low lost ram right?. because in my current device i have TOTAL RAM around 808 MB and LOST RAM around 296 MB which is 36% of it. So that type of device wont be a good choice right ?

Comment: Yea I guess you would want to look for a device with low ram or high available ram. 36% percent lost ram is definitely high, is your OS up to date? And are you possibly running some development or debugging software on it that could be using ram?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. I recently did a factory reset also. But any way i'll do more testing on the device by removing all apps and also checking this on other devices of the same model. And also give me sometime i'll confirm this and mark your answer as a accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not an accurate value, and executing the dump is time-consuming, which can lead to a decrease in computational accuracy. In addition, possible reasons include socket stacking, using some unregulated memory application method to apply for memory, and graphic related memory applications.